# Scraping .aspx page, post request results are not populating

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm attempting to scrape a webpage, but I only want results for a specific reserve bank (New York). I've done some research on scraping .aspx pages and I believe I am capturing all the needed variables in my post request, but I'm still not there.

I've added in various elements from the request body that I can see in inspect element. I keep getting no results as if the search function on the page is never executed.

I can scrape the non-searchable page (https://www.federalreserve.gov/apps/h2a/h2a.aspx) no problem, my results look like this:

```
Applicant: Alberto Joseph Safra, David Joseph Safra and Esther Safra Dayan, Sao Palo, Brazil and Jacob Joseph Safra, Geneva, Switzerland;, Activity: to acquire voting shares of SNBNY Holdings Limited, Gibraltar, Gibraltar and thereby indirectly acquire Safra National Bank of New York, New York, New York., Law: CIBC, Reserve Bank: St. Louis, End of Comment Period: 04/16/2019 

Applicant: American National Bankshares, Inc.,, Activity: to acquire HomeTown Bankshares Corporation, and thereby indirectly acquire HomeTown Bank, both in Roanoke, Virginia ... engage in mortgage lending, also applied to acquire at least 49 percent of HomeTown Residential Mortgage, LLC, Virginia Beach, VA., Law: 3, Reserve Bank: Richmond, End of Comment Period: 02/28/2019 

Applicant: Ameris Bancorp, Moultrie, Georgia;, Activity: to merge with Fidelity Southern Corporation, and thereby indirectly acquire Fidelity Bank, both of Atlanta, Georgia., Law: 3, Reserve Bank: Atlanta, End of Comment Period: 03/14/2019 

Applicant: Amsterdam Bancshares, Inc., Amsterdam, Missouri;, Activity: to acquire 100 percent of the voting shares of S.T.D. Investments, Inc., and thereby indirectly acquire Bank of Minden, both of Mindenmines, Missouri., Law: 3, Reserve Bank: Kansas City, End of Comment Period: 01/04/2019 

Applicant: Amy Beth Windle Oakley, Cookeville, Tennessee, and Mark Edward Copeland, Ooltewah, Tennessee;, Activity: to become members of the Windle/Copeland Family Control Group and thereby retain shares of Overton Financial Services, Inc., and its subsidiary, Union Bank and Trust Company, both of Livingston, Tennessee., Law: CIBC, Reserve Bank: Atlanta, End of Comment Period: 12/27/2018 

Applicant: Anderson W. Chandler Trust A Indenture dated July 25, 1996, and Cathleen Chandler Stevenson, individually, and as trustee, both of Dallas, Texas; Activity: to retain voting shares of Fidelity as members of the Anderson W. Chandler Family Control Group., Law: CIBC, Reserve Bank: Kansas City, End of Comment Period: 06/20/2019 

Applicant: Arthur Haag Sherman, the Sherman 2018 Irrevocable Trust, Sherman Tectonic FLP LP, and Sherman Family Holdings LLC, all of Houston, Texas;, Activity: as a group acting in concert, to acquire shares of T Acquisition, Inc., and thereby indirectly acquire T Bank, National Association, both of Dallas, Texas., Law: CIBC, Reserve Bank: Dallas, End of Comment Period: 12/10/2018 

Applicant: BancFirst Corporation, Oklahoma City, Oklahoma;, Activity: to acquire voting shares of Pegasus Bank, Dallas, Texas., Law: 3, Reserve Bank: Kansas City, End of Comment Period: 06/07/2019 

Applicant: BankFirst Capital Corporation, Macon, Mississippi;, Activity: to merge with FNB Bancshares of Central Alabama, Inc., and thereby indirectly acquire FNB of Central Alabama, both in Aliceville, Alabama., Law: 3, Reserve Bank: St. Louis, End of Comment Period: 02/28/2019
```

Seeing as I want results only for the Federal Reserve Bank of New York, I want to scrape the searchable URL (https://www.federalreserve.gov/apps/h2a/h2asearch.aspx). I have played around with different banks besides New York and none of them yield results using my code. There are results for New York when you search on the webpage. This is what has led me to believe something is wrong with my post request. Here's my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'}

print('Scraping the Latest H2A Release...')

url1 = 'https://www.federalreserve.gov/apps/h2a/h2asearch.aspx'
r1 = requests.get(url=url1, headers=headers)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(r1.text,'html.parser')
viewstate = soup1.findAll("input", {"type": "hidden", "name": "__VIEWSTATE"})
eventvalidation = soup1.findAll("input", {"type": "hidden", "name": "__EVENTVALIDATION"})
stategenerator = soup1.findAll("input", {"type": "hidden", "name": "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"})


item_request_body = {
"__ASYNCPOST": "true",
"__EVENTARGUMENT": "",
"__EVENTTARGET": "",
"__EVENTVALIDATION": eventvalidation[0]['value'],
"__VIEWSTATE": viewstate[0]['value'],
"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": stategenerator[0]['value'],
"ctl00%24bodyMaster%24applicantTextBox":" ",
"ctl00%24bodyMaster%24districtDropDownList": "2",
"ctl00%24bodyMaster%24ScriptManager1": "ctl00%24bodyMaster%24mainUpdatePanel%7Cctl00%24bodyMaster%24searchButton",
"ctl00%24bodyMaster%24searchButton": "Search",
"ctl00%24bodyMaster%24sectionDropDownBox": "ALL",
"ctl00%24bodyMaster%24targetTextBox": ""
}

url = 'https://www.federalreserve.gov/apps/h2a/h2asearch.aspx'
r2 = requests.post(url=url, data=item_request_body, cookies=r1.cookies, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r2.text, 'html.parser')

mylist5 = []
for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[2:]:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    output5 = ("Applicant: %s, Activity: %s, Law: %s, Reserve Bank: %s, End of Comment Period: %s \r\n" % (tds[0].text, tds[1].text, tds[2].text, tds[3].text, tds[4].text))
    mylist5.append(output5)
    print(mylist5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the following script will let you parse the content generated upon selecting `New York`. Try this.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.federalreserve.gov/apps/h2a/h2asearch.aspx'

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
    payload = {item['name']:item.get('value','') for item in soup.select('input[name]')}
    payload['ctl00$bodyMaster$sectionDropDownBox'] = 'ALL'
    payload['ctl00$bodyMaster$districtDropDownList'] = '2'
    del payload['ctl00$bodyMaster$clearButton']
    res = s.post(url,data=payload)
    sauce = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
    for items in sauce.select("table.pubtables tr"):
        data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.select("th,td")]
        print(data)
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. A couple of questions as I am not familiar with .aspx pages. What is the purposes of deleting ('del') the clear button attribute? I am also not super clear what the first payload line means, would you mind elaborating a bit?

Comment: First payload collects most of the necessary parameters meant to be used within post requests. without deleting that clear button you will always send nothing as parameter as that button clears everything you collected to pass with requests.